# Properties of analytic continuation of two point/ Wightman function

Tags: correlation-functions, greens-functions, propagator, qft-in-curved-spacetime, analyticity

In [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.33.3573), the author considers Wightman functions calculated on an accelerating detector for a massless scalar field, namely

$$G_+^R = {}_M \langle 0 | \phi(x) \phi^{\dagger}(x') | 0 \rangle_M$$

$$G_-^R = {}_M \langle 0 | \phi^{\dagger}(x') \phi(x) | 0 \rangle_M$$

where $| 0 \rangle_M$ is the Minkowski vacuum state, and $x$ and $x'$ are actually trajectories of the accelerated detector $x(\tau')$ and $x(\tau'')$. If the analytically continued Wightman function is $\mathcal{G}^R$, then the author argues that since there are no dimensionful parameters, the two point function must be proportional to $[\tau^2]^{1 - n/2}$ where $\tau = \tau'' - \tau'$, if the spacetime is an $n$ dimensional flat spacetime. Therefore, we have poles at $\tau = 0$ when $n$ is even, and hence

$$\mathcal{G}^R(\tau + i \epsilon) = \mathcal{G}^R(\tau - i \epsilon) \quad (\tau \neq 0).$$

This makes sense to me because as long as $\tau \neq 0$, the function is continuous. However, if $n$ is odd, then there is a branch cut because we are essentially taking the square root of $\tau^2$, and the author then says that

$$\mathcal{G}^R(\tau + i \epsilon) = -\mathcal{G}^R(\tau - i \epsilon) \quad (\tau \neq 0).$$

I am not sure how this follows. I understand that there is a discontinuity in the branch cut, but what guarantee do I have that the discontinuity will be of this form? Is there any condition that says that if the separation is spacelike, then the Wightman function $G_+$ and $G_-$ will have the same magnitude? If you have access to the paper, then this is done at equations 4.2a and 4.2b .